# Entity Framework Many-To-8 Relationship?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

This is likely a much broader SQL topic than Entity Framework, and I'm very much a newbie in both these arenas, but I'll ask it in terms of Entity Framework.

I would like to enforce a many-to-8 relationship.  My setup is this:

- A PersonGroup needs 8 (unique) Persons.
- A Person can be in many different PersonGroups.
- The order of the PersonGroup matters (the first needs to remain first, etc).
- Easy access to all people in a PersonGroup and all PersonGroups a Person is in.

I've tried the following:

1) **Add 8 1..many associations between Person and PersonGroup.**  I can certainly not have more than 8 Persons per group using this solution.  However, to find all groups a person is in I need to iterate over 8 variables in the Person field, which is clunky.

2) **Add 8 ids to PersonGroup that match up with a Person.**  Once again, I can guarantee only 8 persons per group, but there is no automatic link back through the association of Person->PersonGroup.  I now need to be sure to add it to two places.

3) **Just do a many...many relationship and handle it in code.**  There are two problems with this: I cannot guarantee only 8 persons per group, and I'm unsure if I can assure the order remains the same.

So, which is the best, or what solution am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `n:m` relationship with a "catch":

```
Person
------
PersonId
PRIMARY KEY (PersonId)


PersonGroup
-----------
GroupId
PRIMARY KEY (GroupId)


Belongs
-------
GroupId
PersonId
Ordering

PRIMARY KEY (GroupId, PersonId)
FOREIGN KEY (GroupId)
  REFERENCES PersonGroup (GroupId)
FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
  REFERENCES Person (PersonId)               --- all normal up to here

UNIQUE KEY (GroupId, Ordering)               --- the "catch"
CONSTRAINT Ordering_chk                      --- ensuring only up to 8 persons 
  CHECK Ordering IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)        --- per group
```

You should make sure that the `CHECK` constraint is available in the SQL engine you'll use (MySQL for example would trick you into believing it has such constraints but it simply ignores them. SQL-Server does not return an error but happily adds a `NULL` in the checked column if you try to insert one.)

There is a limitation to this approach. The `Ordering` field has to be `NOT NULL` because if it is `NULL`, more than 8 rows (with NULL there) could be inserted (except for SQL-Server which would allow you only up to 9 rows, eight with values and one with NULL.)

To ensure maximum of 8 rows and NULLs in the `Ordering`, you could make a more complex constraint like the one described in [MSDN site, CHECK Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) (if your RDBMS has such feature) but I'm not at all sure on the performance of such a beast:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckMax8PersonPerGroup()
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = CASE WHEN EXISTS
                              ( SELECT * 
                                FROM Belongs
                                GROUP BY GroupId
                                HAVING COUNT(*) > 8
                              )
                         THEN 0
                         ELSE 1
                    END 
   RETURN @retval
END;
GO
ALTER TABLE Belongs
ADD CONSTRAINT Ordering_chk 
      CHECK (CheckMax8PersonPerGroup() = 1 );
GO
```

---

The constraint could alternatively be created as a `FOREIGN KEY` to a reference table with 8 rows. (If you use MySQL, that's the only way to have the equivalent of `CHECK`.)

---

A variation would be to use the `(GroupId, Ordering)` as the Primary Key and not have any constraint on the `(GroupId, PersonId)` combination. This would allow for a `Person` having multiple positions in a `Group` (but still up to 8) .

Answer (score 3):

Many-to-many seems ok to me. You can easily make sure there are no more than 8 persons per group by implementing triggers. Also, you can add order column to this table if you think it's important for your logic.